# Fetch time increases while selecting all columns from a table in a multi-table join query

Tags: mysql, join

[image]

**Indexes:**
Table `cell_medicine`

```
index1(cm_id, pvalue)
index2(cell_id)
index3(medicine_id)
index4(dataset_id)
```

On PK in each other tables.

**DBMS**: MySQL 5.7 CE | InnoDB

**Platform**: Azure MySQL as a Service.

**Query**:

```
SELECT ds.*
     , m.*
     , cm.*
     , c.*
  FROM datasets ds
     , medicine m
     , cell_medicine cm
     , cell c 
WHERE cm.cm_id = @var_cm_id 
   AND ds.id = cm.dataset_id 
   AND m.id = cm.medicine_id  
   AND c.id = cm.cell_id
ORDER BY cm.pvalue;
```

The query works fine when I just select the indexed columns. However, it slows down when I want to select every column (`cm.*`) from the cell_medicine table. 
The profiling says it took most of the time on the '`Sending Data`' step.

The table `cell_medicine` has 22M rows and other tables have less than 1K rows. The cardinality of the column `cm_id` is low.

Where should I be directed in order to improve the query or the schema or should consider increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?-The query just takes time for the first execution, however, the `@var_cm_id` changes a lot. Or should look into the IO capabilities of the instance?

Comment: If you just select the indexed columns, the entire result can be calculated just by using the indexes, otherwise it has to access the table files, which is more reading and obviously slower. There's not much you can do about that.

Comment: You can add some "Cover Indices" to Speed up fetching data however it expands storage usage.